# .htaccess query string redirect

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a problem redirecting my sites' old links to the homepage of my site.

To begin with, i'm using these rules to redirect my site to https as i'm using ssl certificate:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Further more i want to redirect my old links like

`http://www.example.com/Default.asp?Network=44448&campaign=89&banner=5147`

to the homepage. There are many links with the same Default.asp page and different query strings which i dont need any more. Any help, mates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this rule below your earlier rule:

```
RewriteRule ^Default\.asp$ /? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesnt work. Wordpress says that page is not found.